# Show that there exists a unique function $h:X\cup Y\to Z$ such that $h\circ\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=f$ and $h\circ\iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=g$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following exercise can be found in Tao’s *Analysis I*.

> **Exercise 3.3.8**(d) Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint sets and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are functions, then there exists a unique function $h:X\cup Y\to Z$ such that $h\circ\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=f$ and $h\circ\iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=g$.

Now, here is my confusion: If $X\cap Y=\varnothing$, then clearly $\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=\operatorname{id}_X$, as $\nexists x\in X : x\in Y$. Similarly, $\iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=\text{id}_Y$. Substitution yields that for suitable $h$, $$h\circ \text{id}_X =f \ \ \land \ \ h\circ\text{id}_Y =g,$$
but this is meaningless — composition is not defined for these functions (as $X\neq Y\neq X\cup Y$). Granted, the original compositions were well-defined. Why have I run into this problem and moreover, how can I continue on the right track?

Comment: Well, notice that $i_{X \to X \cup Y}$ is not $id_X$. The first one is a function from $X$ to $X \cup Y$ and the second one is a function from $X$ to $X$. If that in mind, the identity you wrote has no meaning.

Comment: @Hugocito But, $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint — no element of $X$ is mapped to $Y$

Comment: They have different codomain and therefore they are not the same function.

Comment: Observe that $\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}$ is the inclusion of $X$ into disjoint union $X\cup Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure there exists such $h$. Just define $$h(a)=\begin{cases}
f(a), & \text{if $a\in X$,}\\
g(a), & \text{if $a\in Y$.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then, since $\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}(x)=x$, obviously $h\circ \iota_{X\to X\cup Y}(a)=h(a)=f(a)$, for any $a\in X$. Analogous to $a\in Y$.

Now, suppose that $h'$ also satisfies $h'\circ \iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=f$ and $h'\circ \iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=g$.

So, for any $a\in X$, $$ h'\circ \iota_{X\to X\cup Y}(a)=f(a)= h\circ \iota_{X\to X\cup Y}(a) $$ and by definition of $\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}$ we obtain $$  h'(a)=h(a), \quad \forall\ a \in X.$$

By same argument we get $$  h'(a)=h(a), \quad \forall\ a \in Y.$$

Then, $h=h'$ and there is only one such function.