# Why do we need to prove that functions with "specific properties" exist?

Tags: functions, intuition

There are many exercises I come across where the objective is to prove the existence of a function. Consider the following three examples from various posts on this website:

1) [Conceptual question about assuming the existence of a function in order to prove the existence of another function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585834/conceptual-question-about-assuming-the-existence-of-a-function-in-order-to-prove)

> Let $f:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a function, and let $c$ be a natural number. Show that there exists a function $a : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $$a(0) =c $$
>   and
>   $$a(n++)=f(n,a(n)) \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb N$$

2) [Show that there exists a unique function $h:X\cup Y\to Z$ such that $h\circ\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=f$ and $h\circ\iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=g$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814122/show-that-there-exists-a-unique-function-hx-cup-y-to-z-such-that-h-circ-iota)

> Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint sets and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are functions, then there exists a unique function $h:X\cup Y\to Z$ such that $h\circ\iota_{X\to X\cup Y}=f$ and $h\circ\iota_{Y\to X\cup Y}=g$.

3) [Exercise 3.5.7 of Tao's Analysis I: A question about direct sums.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572544/exercise-3-5-7-of-taos-analysis-i-a-question-about-direct-sums)

> *Let $X,Y$ be sets, and let $\pi_{X\times Y\to X}: X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_{X\times Y\to Y}: X \times Y \to Y$ be the maps $\pi_{X\times Y\to X}(x,y):=x$ and $\pi_{X\times Y\to Y}(x,y):=y$; these maps are known as the co-ordinate functions on $X \times Y$. Show that for any functions $f: Z \to X$ and $g: Z \to Y$, there exists a unique function $h: Z \to X \times Y$ such that $\pi_{X\times Y\to X} \circ h =f$ and $\pi_{X\times Y\to Y} \circ g =f$.*

I recently saw how **Cartesian Products**, the **Power Set Axiom**, and the **Axiom of Specification** could be used to construct a set, denoted $Y^X$, that consists of **all functions** from set $X$ to set $Y$...where $f \in Y^X \iff \text {$f$ is a function with domain $X$ and range $Y$}$. The proof can be found here: [Hints for proving that the collection of all set functions whose domain is the set $X$ and whose range is a subset or equal to the set $Y$ is a set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578158/hints-for-proving-that-the-collection-of-all-set-functions-whose-domain-is-the-s).

---

Now, referring back to the three aforementioned examples, in all three cases, **we already know the domain and codomain**.

For the first example, $a \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$. In the second example, $h \in (X \cup Y) ^{Z}$. In the third example, $h \in Z^{X \times Y}$.

Because we know that the set $codomain^{domain}$ exists, and such a set contains all functions that have these corresponding domains and codomains, I fail to see why any proof needs to occur at all.

Regardless of the properties that functions $a$ and $h$ have, they must already exist because if the set that contains them exists, then clearly so do the elements of said set!

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the set of all sets is a set with a specified property. Why do you need to prove it exists? Why not just "trust me, 'saul good, man" instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't see why a problem is nontrivial, it often helps to consider silly variations of it which are outright *wrong*.

---

To start with, consider:

> Show that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$, and $f(3)=17$.

When we write "Show that there exists a function such that [stuff]," what we're proving is that [stuff] *is actually a satisfiable constraint*. Knowing that the set of all functions with the given domain/codomain exists is irrelevant: we know that *if* a function with the properties we want exists then it's in that set, but *does it actually exist in the first place*?

Uniqueness is similarly nontrivial. Consider:

> Show that there is a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x+2)=f(x)+2$.

Again, we have a certain property $P$ of functions that we want to understand. The set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ of all functions with the appropriate domain/codomain exists, but that doesn't help answer the question: **how many functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $P$**? (In particular, for existence we need "$\ge 1$" and for uniqueness we need "exactly $1$").

Comment: For clarification, if I were to assume that $f$ was a function, the "silly variation" you provided says that $f(3)$ simultaneously equals $3$ and $17$. A function cannot map a single element in its domain to more than one value...and so we have a contradiction because we have previously asserted that $f$ IS a function. Thus, $f$ must not be a function. That is how that argument would be constructed, correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes - the properties in question (is a function $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, $f(0)=0$, $f(3)=17$) are not satisfiable. There's nothing special about functions here, of course - this is the same way we prove nonexistence of any type of object.

Comment: Interesting, interesting. So it seems like there are only two ways that a function could be found to "not exist". They are 1) if the properties lead to a scenario where one element in the domain outputs to two or more elements...and 2) if the properties lead to a scenario where an element in the domain does NOT land in the specified codomain.  Would you agree with that understanding?

Comment: @S.Cramer No. We could also have a situation where it has a paradoxical "global" property. For example, "a surjective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: ahhh. So the " 3) " would basically be: "The properties cannot be fulfilled".

Comment: @S.Cramer Well, that subsumes (1) and (2). I would rather say that (1) and (2) are *types* of impossibility but don't exhaust the whole. But ultimately this just becomes aesthetic.

Comment: Very informative. Thanks a bunch! Cheers~